# not able to add icon in ion-select header

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using ion-select and I want a close icon button in the select header. I'm unable to do it. Can somebody help me to implement it.

[image]

My code:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Pet</ion-label>
    <ion-select placeholder="Select One">
      <ion-select-option value="f">Cat</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="m">Dog</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the ion-label to below code. hope it helps

```
    <a class="item item-icon-right" style="text-align: center;">        
          Pet
    <i class="icon ion-ios-close-outline"></i>
    </a>
```

Comment: Its not working...I want the icon in the select menu after it is opened, not in the label